# reference request: lie algebra-lie group

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am looking for a reference where I can find a (relatively) elementary and self contained proof of the fact that all real, finite dimensional Lie algebras are the Lie algebra of some Lie group.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried P. J. Olver (https://www.amazon.com/Applications-Differential-Equations-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387950001?ie=UTF8&*Version*=1&*entries*=0)

Comment: The fact you're looking for is known as [Ado's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ado%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

The statement is known as *Lie's third Theorem*: Every finite-dimensional real Lie algebra $L$ is integrable, that is, there exists a Lie group $G$ with $Lie(G)\cong L$. For a proof see, for example, the note by J. Ebert [Van Est's exposition of Cartan's proof of Lie's third theorem](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/u/jeber_02/talks/lieIII.pdf), and the references.

Remark: Lie's third theorem is also a corollary to Ado's theorem, see [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/ados-theorem/). However, I think that the proof of Ado's theorem is perhaps more difficult to understand than the proof of Lie's third theorem.